# How to save $this to be used as selector for parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a button value in jQuery to erase a row.  button value is the rowID.  After success, I need a way to call `$(this).closest('tr').hide()`  to remove the row.

Anyway to do this without labeling every `<tr>` with specific row IDs?

Alright, here is some code:

```
var rowID = $( this ).attr('value'); 

var data = { 
    'action': 'my_delete_row_action', 
    'id': rowID
}
```

`$(this)` is a `<button>` element with a `value` set to `$row[id]`.

After deleting the row, I need a way to do:

`$(this).closest('tr').hide()` - which would use the currently active button, grab the parent `<tr>` and remove it from the table.

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup?

Comment: Need more code and HTML... can't compute... feed me!!!

Comment: var rowID = $( this ).attr('value');

var data = { 'action': 'my_delete_row_action', 'id': rowID }

$(this) is a element with a value=$row[id]

after deleting the row, I need a way to do:

$(this).closest('tr').hide() - which would use the currently active button, grab the parent and remove it from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using ajax to delete entities server-side, and you want to remove specific row on client on success:

```
$("table").on("click", "button.delete", function(){
    var $button = $(this), //save reference to the button clicked
        rowId= = $button.attr("value"),
        data = {"id": rowId, ...};

    $.ajax(...).done(function(){
        $button.closest("tr").hide(); //or remove or whatever.
    });
});
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I wanted.  I am still learning jQuery, and this was driving me nuts! Thank you Yury

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to bind the button (or anything else) as context:

```
$.ajax({
  // All the other AJAX options
  context: $(this),  // Magic key to bind the async callback into the original context
  success: function() {
    // Now $(this) is your button
  }
});
```

Comment: I thought context was depreciated?

Comment: No mentions about it being deprecated in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/